Create a single quoted list macro variable from a data column in sas
If I have a data set with a column like this:
ID
A1028
A30900
B7018


I am trying to convert this to a list with the values in single quotes, separated by commas like this:
&ID= 'A1028','A30900','B7018'
I can make a comma separated list by:
proc sql;
select distinct ID
into :ID separated by ","
from data;
quit; 

to get
&ID= A1028,A30900,B7018
But I can't find how to add single quotes. I have tried several solutions, but they have double quotations. Ultimately I am trying to use this macro variable to filter a larger data set:
proc sql;
select * 
from data2
where ID in (&ID.)
quit;

But I think it will only work with single quotes because ID is a character value. It did not work with unquoted IDs or double quoted IDs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code you showed will work with either single or double quotes. SAS does not care except in PROC SQL with the DQUOTE=ANSI option selected.   Unless the IN operator is being passed by you directly into a foreign database.  Then the code would need to follow the syntax rules for that database's implementation of SQL.

Add the quotes in the SAS code and avoid having to worry about it in macro code.  You can use the QUOTE() function.
select distinct quote(trim(ID),"'")
  into :ID separated by ','
  from data
;

The TRIM() function will make so the strings generated will not including the meaningless trailing spaces into the macro variables.  Do not use the StRIP() function as that will also remove leading spaces, which are meaningful.
And if you are only going to use the list to generate SAS code (ie not as part of explicitly pass-thru SQL query) then use a space instead of a comma as the separator.  The IN operator in SAS will allow you to use either a comma or a space (or some combination of both).  And a macro variable without commas is a lot easier to use for other things in SAS macro code.

Before I know quote() function, I used separated by '","' instead, well, your method is much more robust!

Use the cats function to add single quotes. In SAS, in() accepts both single and double quotes so the only reason why it wouldn't work is if the data doesn't exist. Just to help out, I want to provide you with how to create a single-quoted macro list in SQL just in case you need it in the future.
proc sql;
    select distinct cats("'", ID, "'")
    into :ID separated by ","
    from data;
quit; 

However, if you're going to be filtering one dataset with another, why not do an inner join?
proc sql;
    select t2.* 
    from data as t1, data2 as t2
    where t1.id = t2.id;
quit;

Or, alternatively:
proc sql;
    select * 
    from data2
    where id in(select id from data);
quit;


You might consider QUOTE function it will handle quotes within the string QUOTE(strip(id),"'")

Hi, Stu. Have you compared performance of these skills? May select into + in operator be the fastest table lookup method?

You'll have to try it out yourself to see which is faster. It depends on the size of the data, whether it's indexed or not, and a number of other factors.
